# random error in Moodle. New Insight: No Teaching

Tags: moodle

Out of the ordinary, one of my students is receiving this random email:

[image]

Neither my support team, nor myself know what this means.
Can someone enlighten me to tell me what it means, and how to rectify this error (if that's what it is?)

Thanks.

Comment: Looks like that is part of the Analytics feature that was added to core in 3.4. The Moodle docs at https://moodle.org/mod/forum/discuss.php?d=365850 explain how to turn it off for a user.

Comment: Just to make sure I"m not turning something valid off, is this a valid error?